# time faked by "faketime" as non-frozen is not ticking

Tags: linux

I need to fake time for java app (that's the reason for --exclude-monotonic), I need to specify exact timestamp, but I need clock to tick, not to be frozen. For that behavior IIUC I have to use say following demonstrative command:

```
faketime --exclude-monotonic -f "@2030-11-02 12:47:00" bash -c 'watch -n 0.5 date';
```

omitting `--exclude-monotonic` does not make the difference. Observed behavior is `watch` command in upper right corner is ticking in year 2030 (great!), but date produced by `date` is not ticking, and is stuck at start time. I have same stuck behavior in java app, but provided example demonstrates the issue better.

Why is that?

Comment: actually I have the work done already using the offset you mentioned (`-f "+10y"`). But it was a little bit cumbersome, as I had to parameterize app so that I need not to wait for midnight. Doable, but not ideal. When faking time, I'd really like to set time 2 minutes before midnight using faketime. And yes, you were correct, faketime fakes the time only  for top-level command, in this case `watch`. I ran some java process without bash and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the command you've tried, the clock start time is applied to each and every command executed within the `faketime` environment. Indeed, the `@` symbol declares that all subprocesses should start from this absolute time. When using the advanced formatting there is no easy way to declare a shared and self-consistent starting point for all subprocesses:

```
faketime --exclude-monotonic -f "@2030-11-02 12:47:00" bash -c 'watch -n 0.5 date'
```

Here, the time for `watch` is at odds with the time reported by `date`.

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime/blob/master/src/libfaketime.c) I notice that this behaviour is only applied when the "advanced timestamp specification format" is active (i.e. you've used `-f`):

```
case '@': /* Specific time, but clock along relative to that starttime */
```

The `+` symbol declares a relative offset, but to determine the relative offset you would have to perform date maths and subtract the current date/time from the target starting date:

```
offset=$(( $(date --date '2030-11-02 12:47:00' +%s) - $(date +%s) ))
faketime --exclude-monotonic -f "+$offset" bash -c 'watch -n 0.5 date'
```

Horrible.

Fortunately, your particular timestamp format can be parsed correctly without needing advanced formatting, and this will provide the behaviour you want:

```
faketime --exclude-monotonic "2030-11-02 12:47:00" bash -c 'watch -n 0.5 date'
```

Comment: thanks! Helped a lot. However I kinda don't understand, why your solution without advanced format works as it should, why advanced format using @ does not

Comment: The code is written to use `@` as an instruction to reset the clock from the starting point for each process and subprocess.

Comment: aha! Very nice. Can be useful. Thanks a lot!